# Passando parâmetros para um executável

Tags: c#

Eu possuo uma aplicação que é dividida em dois executáveis diferentes.

O primeiro executável é o ‘cérebro’ da minha aplicação, nesse executável, no qual eu o nomeei de STUB, ficará toda a lógica principal da aplicação com alguns métodos adicionais e optativos (alguns obrigatórios, porém, variáveis), como hosts, portas, pop-ups, etc.

O segundo executável é exatamente a parte do optativo e do obrigatório, na qual eu o chamo de UI, ou seja, o usuário irá escolher as opções que deseja e a partir dessa UI, criar o novo executável.

Utilizando a minha STUB como um *.exe base, eu quero que minha UI dê um re-write na minha STUB setando as opções definidas pelo usuário, criando assim um novo executável que funcionará de acordo com as opções que o usuário escolheu.

O único tipo de aplicação que consigo recordar possuir tal funcionalidade são os RATs (Remote Administration Tools) e alguns Keyloggers, no qual você pode criar um servidor de conexão remota para controlar um computador, e nessa criação você pode definir diversas opções (seu ip, local de instalação, etc.). Os servidores de conexão também são gerados a partir de um *.exe base.

Peguei uma imagem aleatória do google para exemplificar, nela, há uma janela de customização de um RAT (Note que a última aba é justamente a de construção do *.exe com as configurações pré-definidas):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

@UPDATE: Não sei se ajuda mas, revirando códigos pré-históricos eu encontrei um código em VB6 que faz algo parecido. Ele pega um o arquivo STD.exe que inicialmente não faz nada e em cima dele cria um outro (RWSTD.exe) acrescentando uma MsgBox() quando o mesmo iniciar. Já tentei pesquisar a função dessas linhas de código e tentar replicar em C#, porém, sem sucesso. Observem os códigos:

Cliente UI:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim STD As String, RWSTD As String, MID As String, DEL As String
    DEL = "DELIMITADOR"

    Open App.Path & "\STD.exe" For Binary As #1
    STD = Space(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , STD
    Close #1

    If FileExists(App.Path & "\RWSTD.exe") Then
        Kill App.Path & "\RWSTD.exe"
    End If

    Open App.Path & "\RWSTD.exe" For Binary As #1
    RWSTD = Space(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , RWSTD
    Put #1, , STD & DEL & txtMsgBox.Text
    Close #1

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Not FileExists("STD.exe") Then
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

STB.exe:

```
Sub Starter()
    Dim DATA As String, DEL() As String, i As Long

    Open App.Path & "\" & App.EXEName & ".exe" For Binary As #1
    DATA = Space(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , DATA
    Close #1

    DEL() = Split(DATA, "DELIMITADOR")

    For i = 1 To UBound(DEL)
        If Not (DEL(i) = "MZ") Then
            MsgBox (DEL(i))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Eu não quero nem passar/recuperar arquivos à outro executável por execução. O que eu desejo fazer e está escrito na pergunta é rebuildar minha stub com algumas opções específicas, ou seja, geraria um novo *.exe em cima do stub, porém, com as modificações que o usuário realizou no cliente.

Comment: Um exemplo funcional do que eu exatamente quero é o funcionamento de um RAT (Remote Administration Tool), nele, há uma stub que origina todos os servidores criados, porém, você pode customizar as opções e buildar um novo executável sempre que quiser. Assim, podemos ter como exemplo um executável que se instalará no Desktop e outro no %appdata%, porém, ambos foram gerados a partir da mesma base (a stub).

Comment: entendi, já vi algo parecido em programa `deep freeze`, a partir dele você gera um executavel que irá ser instalado na máquina cliente

Comment: tente ser um pouco mais claro na pergunta, é um assunto interessante e se não estiver clara o suficiente, será fechada. Vou acompanhar a questão

Comment: Tentei explicar o máximo que pude, adicionei a parte dos rats. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Há também alguns keyloggers que trabalham assim. Você tem a aplicação principal, e gera um novo executável com as opções escolhidas por você. Esse executável, uma vez instalado no cliente, seguirá as informações que você determinou pela aplicação principal. Só mais um exemplo pra tentar ajudar na explicação.

Comment: Não consigo explicar mais que isso.

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [Modify Emdeded String in C# compiled exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742583/modify-emdeded-string-in-c-sharp-compiled-exe)

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [Modify Emdeded String in C# compiled exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742583/modify-emdeded-string-in-c-sharp-compiled-exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se deseja alterar valores de strings que estão dentro do executável, você pode fazer o seguinte:

1) Converta o executável em um arquivo IL (Intermediate language);
2) Faça um search/replace no arquivo IL.
3) Recompile o IL para gerar o novo executável.

O .NET SDK possui a ferramenta [Ildasm.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx) para fazer essa conversão.