# Compilando arquivo .il (Intermediate Language) com permissão de admin

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, permissões

Andei pesquisando bastante sobre como inserir certos parâmetros em um executável já criado. E cheguei [nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247679/passando-par%C3%A2metros-para-um-execut%C3%A1vel) da Stack

Porém o programa inicialmente possui privilégios de administrador. Só que ao recompilar, ele perde essa permissão. Como proceder para compilar um arquivo `.il` com permissões de admin?

Answer (score 1):

Compilação e permissão nada tem a ver, quem instala o software é que dá permissão do que ele pode fazer, um executável criado não tem propriedade de privilégio, então a pergunta nem faz sentido. Então terá que pedir a permissão e o usuário determinará se dá ou não. Muitas vezes um instalador pode ajudar nisso. Nem poderia ser diferente, caso contrário fazer ataques serão extremamente simples.

Na verdade nem faz sentido fazer o que fez. A pergunta e principalmente resposta *linkada* são bem ruins, não precisa fazer aquilo que a pessoa disse para obter o resultado pedido, nem faz sentido fazer aquilo que ela queria, é só um "solução" errada para a real necessidade.

Comment: Então qual seria a forma correta de perguntar e qual seria a solução correta pra esse problema (alterar parâmetros de um executável)

Comment: E sobre a compilação, eu só quis dizer que ele perde a permissão de adm quando eu compilo um arquivo `.il`. Foi basicamente [isso que eu fiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator) na aplicação, inicialmente, pra que ela peça permissão de adm ao ser executada.

Comment: OS parâmetros não devem estar no executável, simples.

Comment: Mas para deixar mais prático pro usuário, o que eu quero fazer, precisa. Explicando melhor, o usuário vai escolher determinadas coisas em um site, e eu tenho que mandar pra ele um executável com os parâmetros de acordo com o que ele escolheu...

Comment: Isso não é mais prático e é errado. Ache a solução adequada, esta não é.

Comment: É, eu sempre prezo por boas práticas. Mas a única forma que achei foi essa. Porque o programa que eu fiz, instala alguns programas no modo **silent**. É basicamente [isso](https://ninite.com) que quero fazer. Você conhece/indica outra alternativa pra solucionar esse problema? Estou fazendo isso para fins de aprendizado ao C#